# List the top 3 selling product for every year

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

The Question is "List the top 3 selling product for every year"

I executed following query

```
select top 3 b.CalendarYear,c.ProductKey, d.EnglishProductSubcategoryName ,SUM(a.SalesAmount) as SALES
from FactInternetSales as A inner join dimdate as B
on a.OrderDateKey =b.DateKey
inner join DimProduct as c
on c.ProductKey = a.ProductKey
inner join DimProductSubcategory as d
on c.ProductSubcategoryKey = d.ProductSubcategoryKey
inner join  DimProductCategory as e 
on d.ProductCategoryKey=e.ProductCategoryKey
group by b.CalendarYear,c.ProductKey, d.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
order by SALES desc
```

i got following answer

```
CalendarYear    ProductKey  EnglishProductSubcategoryName    SALES
2006    312 Road Bikes  658401.68
2006    313 Road Bikes  608305.90
2006    310 Road Bikes  608305.90
```

My query is how only "year 2006" data came why not all years?

Comment: Can't be [mySQL].  MySQL doesn't use `TOP n` syntax.

Comment: are you sure you got the tag right? `select top 3` is not mysql syntax

Comment: Road bikes were hot in 2006.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use top keyword. If you can than the result of the query is correct cause it gives you just 3 records. In that way you cannot yeld 3records for each group! let try another way

Comment: its SQL server not my sql

Comment: @baudo2048  then what should i use if i want top 3 records for every year

Comment: are you using sql server?

Comment: yes m using SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query..

```
   ; WITH cte_1
     AS
     ( SELECT CalendarYear,ProductKey
                      ,EnglishProductSubcategoryName,SALES
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY
                           CalendarYear,ProductKey
                          ,EnglishProductSubcategoryName
                       ORDER BY Sales DESC) RNO
         FROM (select b.CalendarYear,c.ProductKey
                                ,d.EnglishProductSubcategoryName
                                ,SUM(a.SalesAmount) as SALES
                       from FactInternetSales as A 
                           inner join dimdate as B
                                 on a.OrderDateKey =b.DateKey
                           inner join DimProduct as c
                                on c.ProductKey = a.ProductKey
                           inner join DimProductSubcategory as d
                                on c.ProductSubcategoryKey = d.ProductSubcategoryKey
                           inner join  DimProductCategory as e 
                                on d.ProductCategoryKey=e.ProductCategoryKey
                        group by b.CalendarYear,c.ProductKey
                          ,  d.EnglishProductSubcategoryName)t
  )
   SELECT CalendarYear,ProductKey
                      ,EnglishProductSubcategoryName,SALES
    FROM cte_1
    WHERE RNO<4
    ORDER BY CalendarYear DESC,RNO ASC
```

In the script provided you are only selecting the top3 records from the result set.so you are getting ony 3 records as output.

Comment: thanks unnikrishnan R , as i am new learner this answer is very usefull to me,will u please tell me how and when we need to use CTE functions ??

Comment: In simple words,we can say that CTE will act as a temp table which holds a result set on which we can apply filters or criteria,ie we can use the result set for further calculation.But we can also use CTE for recursive querying also.. you can learn more on recursive cte on this link  [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The general idea could be to add a column counter to each group of rows (1 2 3 ...) and then select the records were counter is less or equals to 3